# how chargify billing will be integrate in our site with fee fighter samurai payemt gateway

Tags: payment-gateway, chargify

I'm working on a site where I have to integrate the Chargify billing system with the Fee Fighter Samurai payment gateway. How do I integrate them? 
I also found an example on the Gateway site, but it is not enough. 
I want to integrate this in PHP.

I used the below example implementation which is provided by gateway
for Fee Fighter Samurai at github:
https://github.com/FeeFighters/samurai-example-php

For Chargify billing system:
https://github.com/ajshort/silverstripe-chargify

But how can I use both in one site in signup page?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. This community is focused on answering specific programming questions. In its current form your question is very broad. You are more likely to recieve helpful answers if you update the question to detail your current understanding of the integration process, specific parts you are struggling with, and the efforts you have made to overcome the issues you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

Actually - it looks like you're just a little confused about how the two are separated.

First, submit a ticket here: http://help.chargify.com and let us know which site you want the Samurai gateway enabled for.

Second, integrate Chargify into your site using any wrapper or code you wish - but just remember to only think about Chargify, not FeeFighters or Samurai. Chargify abstracts that part of it away from you, the developer, so that you just interact with Chargify and that's it.

Comment: thanks for suggest me.  in my site fee samurai gateway is enabled. so now i have to only integrate the chargify code not the samurai. ifi make code for the chargify then it will automatically implement the fee fighter samurai?